# Object Permissions in salesforce

Tags: user

I have a admin user. Inside admin user so many users are created. For particular user, `userrole` object is Not accessible. How to add the userrole object or give permissions for particular user in salesforce.

Comment: Is userrole custom object and admin user a profile.

Comment: userrole is a standard object in salesforce

Comment: Which user can't access userrole? Is that user a portal user

Comment: it is not a portal user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable following permissions on Profile to access UserRole.

These permission are found in "[Administrative Permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000198725&language=en_US&type=1)" section of Profile.

Manage Roles - Allows the user to create, edit, and delete roles.

Manage Users - Allows the user to create, edit, and deactivate users, and manage security settings, including profiles and roles.

Answer (score 0):

As UserRole is special kind of standard object I don't think you can give access to certain objects. Their permissions are not associated with them directly and are determined by its parent object. Navigate to **Manage Users** > **Profiles** > **Object Settings**. You can edit access for available objects there.
Portal users can't access `userrole`.